# Using finfo on a VPS

Tags: php, mime-types

I've tested that this works locally, but now that I've moved my content to a godaddy VPS, I'm finding some problems.

I contacted support about it and they told me to research this.

What I have found is that this code:

```
   $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME, "../../../../../etc/httpd/conf/magic");
```

Is pointing to the correct location, but according to support, the webuser does not have access.

What would be the safest way to go about this?  I'm relatively new to server management.

EDIT: UPDATE

Only the php.ini file is contained in /etc, which makes /etc/httpd/conf/magic an invalid path for me to use. My local dev machine is Ubuntu Linux.  Would I be able to chmod on-the-fly in my PHP code somehow?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `/etc/httpd/conf/magic` as the path (I'm assuming that's where you end up)?

Comment: u are using a vps. u just need to chmod.

Comment: I presume you are using non Unix machine for your local development like Windows where most of the processes run under same credential. On Unix platforms there are much more restriction who have an access to each folder. So my suggestion would be to make sure that folder you are trying to access belong to same user group as your web server.

Comment: Only the php.ini exists in /etc, so /etc/httpd/conf/magic isn't a valid path for me to use.  Do I chmod in my php code?  I'm doing local dev work in Ubuntu Linux 12.04LTS

Comment: Either change the permissions of the target file or copy it somewhere where your user has permission to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# chmod +r /etc/httpd/conf/magic
```

This will give your users read permission.

Comment: Tried this. Got an error:  "myusername" is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

Comment: Do you actually have root access on the VPS? If not, you won't be able to give users access to folders you need root to access (by design). It may be best to move whatever you're trying to access to another location owned by your www-user.

Comment: I originally tried to do a sudo command, I tried again using an su command. This is the current permissions list for the magic file:       -rw-r--r-- root root magic

Comment: Try using an absolute location, without the `..`s.

Comment: Got it.  I copied the magic file into /etc. Thanks for your help.